# Are there any templates to make Ruby code in Netbeans look as sexy as in Textmate?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, code-formatting

As much as I love Netbeans for Ruby programming the traditional white background and drab color coding leave me with Textmate envy.

Is there any solution to this in the absence of buying a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dark color schemes in NetBeans](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/06/dark-color-schemes-in-netbeans.html)

[Aloha Color Theme](http://blog.huikau.com/2008/01/25/aloha-color-theme-for-netbeans-6/)

[Google netbeans color schemes](http://www.google.com/search?q=netbeans+color+schemes)

Comment: wtf!? how does this get -1?? Aloha Color Theme is pretty close to Textmate.

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin called *Extra color themes*:

> Additional editor color themes designed for use with the Ruby file types in NetBeans. The 'Dark Pastels' theme was designed by Jerrett Taylor. The 'Aloha' theme was created by Mike McKinney (http://huikau.com)

did you tried it?

Comment: Editor cat lieks your grammar?!>.

Answer (score 0):

I use the *Dark Psstels* theme from the *Extra Ruby Color Themes* plugin. Be advised, though, that NetBeans only allows you to style the *editor*, the rest of the IDE will still look as butt-ugly as it did before. (Pardon my French.)

If you want to change *that*, you will have to change the entire Swing Look&Feel. There are also some plugins which do that, but they are mostly for testing. (There is one which switches NetBeans to the Napkin LAF, which as the name implies makes everything look like it's scribbled on a napkin. This is very useful if you use the NetBeans Application Platform to build your *own* NetBeans-based applications (does anybody do that?), but otherwise pretty useless.)

Note that this isn't much of a problem if you maximize the editor and put NetBeans in fullscreen mode.